# Multiple synchronized HTML 5 video on each other and remove on disconnect/behind, good idea?

Tags: html, video, streaming, distribution

I am trying to find a simple yet powerful way to distribute the "video" load over several nodes in an network, there each node way get disconnected in any time, just as in the bit-torrent network.

IDEA
To put multiple HTML 5 video elements over each other using CSS position attributes and play them all synchronized. Those video elements who get behind too much (or get disconnected) should be removed and if the number of video elements is close to zero should a new video URL get fetched from the server.

PHILOSOPHY 
Makes thing in parallel, and take the best.

CODE EXAMPLE:

HTML:

```
<div class="header">            
        <video>
        <source src='path1/video.webm' type='video/webm; codecs="vp8.0, vorbis"'/>
        </video>

        <video>
        <source src='another/path/video.webm' type='video/webm; codecs="vp8.0, vorbis"'/>
        </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.header {
    position:relative;
}
div.header video {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Is this a good idea? Is it possible? Why not then? Profs and cons?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a little like solving an ant infestation by blowing up one's house with a nuke.

Having multiple synced streams like this:

- is overly complex, increasing chance of failure
- increases load on your infrastructure (as you're serving the same video multiple times to the same user), increasing chance of failure
- increases the bandwidth requirements for your users (as they're downloading the same video multiple times), increasing chance of failure
- likely won't be perfectly synced ever, so users will hear echoing audio

I'd focus on making your video serving nodes reliable, or offload it to a CDN.

Comment: 1. How is it "overly complex" ?
2. It is not my infrastructure, that is the whole point.
3. I know, but it may be possible to pause/start others videos depending how the currently source is behaving.

Comment: 1. It's overly complex because it's like reading three books in parallel in case one of them lights on fire. 2. That wasn't really clear in your question. If reliable video delivery is this important to you, you might want to use your own infrastructure. 3. You'd still presumably be loading the content for the duplicates, though, which if nothing else is potentially going to make the videos stutter for the video if their connection is crap.